# How to extend session cookie lifetime in Symfony?

Tags: php, session, cookies, symfony

On accessing session data on the server side, its `modified_time` gets set, therefore extending its expiration time into the future.

However, this does not happen for `PHPSESSID` cookie. While session data expiration on the server side is extended, the cookie expiration is not. If the cookie expires, the user will lose his session - he will have no session ID to give when sending a request.

Is there any way to tell `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session` to extend the cookie expiration date?

- Can this be done for the same session ID? Or will we have to regenerate it (seems inefficient to do for many users X many requests)?
- Should I set it myself manually (disregarding the OOP principles)

I've found `$request->getSession()->getMetadataBag()`
and tried setting `stampNew()`, but this does not seem to interact with the `PHPSESSID` cookie.

Comment: I thought the PHPSESSID cookie was set as a session cookie meaning that the browser would clean it up when it was closing. Never heard of it being cleaned up before the browser session was done.

Comment: I don't need to delete it, I need to extend its expiration date. It won't be cleared on closing the browser - the cookie will live for much longer (kind of like REMEMBERME, I'm guessing)

Comment: What I'm saying is (based on [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime) the default duration of the session is "as long as the browser is open"). Now if a browser does not do a cleanup of session cookies and keeps them a bit longer (which is often the case) is not based on default PHP configuration. At any rate a PHP session is not meant to persist past a browser session, perhaps you could use a different session manager and your own custom sessionid cookie to persist the session for longer.

Answer (score 1):

You can change in the config.yml files under the session key, as example:

```
# session configuration
session:
    cookie_lifetime:    3600
```

From the doc:

> cookie_lifetime
>
> type: integer default: null
>
> This determines the lifetime of the session - in seconds. The default
>   value - null - means that the session.cookie_lifetime value from
>   php.ini will be used. Setting this value to 0 means the cookie is
>   valid for the length of the browser session.

More info in the doc [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#cookie-lifetime)

Comment: I'm aware of this setting, what I need to know is how to "bump" the cookie expiration time on every page visit, because the expiration time of the session data on the server is "bumped" on every request. Also long as keep visiting the site, your session should be alive for the defined lifetime, even after you close the browser (and then come back on). It should only die if you haven't visited the site for the `lifetime` seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I had a hard time to make this work but I finally got it:
I'm working in Symfony 5.4 and wanted to extend the session dynamically. I stripped out some of my logic but it comes down to this Listener:

```
<?php

namespace CoreBundle\Event;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;

class SessionExtender implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        readonly private TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage,
    ) {
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            // Important, our Response listener must come after the core SessionListener
            // See: Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\AbstractSessionListener
            // -> KernelEvents::RESPONSE => ['onKernelResponse', -1000],
            KernelEvents::RESPONSE => ['checkSessionExtension', -1001],
        ];
    }
    
    public function checkSessionExtension(ResponseEvent $event): void
    {
        if (!$event->isMainRequest()) {
            return;
        }

        $request = $event->getRequest();
        
        /**
         * Only extends the session on a selection of routes. Prevents this logic to execute on every request
         */
        $route = $request->get('_route');
        if (!in_array($route, [
            // A list of routes which can tell we have human interaction...
            'some_route',
            'some_other_route',
        ])) {
            return;
        }

        if (!$this->tokenStorage->getToken()?->getUser()) {
            return;
        }

        $session = $request->getSession();
        if (!$session) {
            return;
        }
        
        // Some more logic...

        // Extend the session with 3600 seconds
        // "destroy" option must be "true" make the lifetime extend properly
        $session->migrate(true, 3600);

        // Save & close & start or the "migrate" above has no effect!
        $session->save();
        $session->start();
    }
}
```

And register it in services.yml

```
CoreBundle\Event\SessionExtender:
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```